# Magento -how are pages differentiated?

Tags: templates, layout, magento

I'm a little confused with the way Magento implements web pages, and I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

I've figured out how to adjust themes and templates, etc., but I'm wondering how I implement content with them.

There is a disconnect in my understanding of how to put content into a page.  Is this done with the layout and template files, or is this done on the cms page?

I've been searching for tutorials, etc., and I'm having trouble finding them (maybe I'm using the wrong terminology), so if you know of examples or anything that might help, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento design/template is a broad question, which may appears tricky at first, but so logical and powerfull once you get to know it.
In a nutshell, the .xml layout files are responsible for defining the content, and the phtml (in relation with their Block classes) actually render the html. Everytime a page load, all the layout files are parsed to retrieve all the blocks which have to appears in this particular page.

The content loaded in each page is defined by the handles in the layout files, which correspond to the module/controller/action. For example, the content of the **customer's account index** page (which is the result of the **index** action, of the **Account** Controller of the **Customer** module, see the logic of the handle's name) is defined by:

- the blocks/layout defined in the `<customer_account_index>` handle of app/design/PACKAGE/TEMPLATE/layout/customer.xml
- the blocks/layout defined in the `<customer_account_index>` handle of all other layout files (I'm not saying that all layout files have a `<customer_account_index>` handle, but those who have it, like poll.xml, will insert their content)
- the blocks/layout defined in the `<default>` handle of all other layout files, that's why it's called "default" :)

When you say:

> is this done on the cms page?

I assume you're refering to the cms in the admin: this only take care of the content block of the static pages of your store. And the rest of the page is still defined by the xml (the page.xml handle of the cms page's layout (1 column, 2 columns-left, etc...) handles like `<default>`, `<cms_index_index>`, etc...) But even there, you can modify the layout by putting content in the proper textareas.

Here are some interesting links to understand the magic of Magento's layout:

- [Demystifying Magento’s Layout XML](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)
- [Magento for Developers: Part 4 - Magento Layouts, Blocks and Templatese](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)
- [No Frills Magento Layout by Alan Storm](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/no-frills-magento-layout)
- [Designer's Guide to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide)

HTH

Comment: I'm trying to learn Magento on my own, and it's been a little tricky for me.
So, it sounds like I want to be creating my own .phtml files so I can control the layout beyond the main content area.  Do you know how I might be able to find examples of how to create a custom template file?  There seem to be plenty of skeleton files, but I still don't really understand where all the php references point, and where the actual data is stored or referenced (or whatever is actually happening.)  I think I'm beginning to understand how to do layouts in theory, but in practice I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: you should really read the links I've put: the .phtml files don't control the layout, the .xml files do. The designer's guide to magento explains how to create/edit your store templates. the php reference points to the Block classes, and the layout with the `type` attribute indicates which class is that. As I said, it seems tricky at first, but trust me, I also learned it by myself and I can assure you it's not impossible.

Comment: I thought I had read the designer's guide to magento, but it turns out that I had only read about a 1/3 or it before being distracted.  It turns out that it's quite a good resource.  Thank you.